# Sencha touch + phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I need to develop an app in Sencha touch and phonegap in android.I got decent performance in iphone.
Does it produce good performance in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sencha touch 2 for android. They have improved the performance significantly and also resolved most of the issues on android. To use phonegap you need android 2.2 so most of the devices that have this OS have good performance so you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

It'll depend on the device.

In my experience web apps don't perform any where near as well on Android as they do on iPhone. Specifically, many Android devices don't support hardware acceleration on the web which can make transitions between pages jerky, and scrolling panes rather slow. An app which looks and performs great on iPhone can look a little 'retro' on some Android devices. I'm sure there are newer, faster Android devices I haven't tried which are much better though!

Make sure you can get hold of some real devices to test on.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just started using Sencha and Phonegap, it looks good especially if you need a quick solution.

Using the Eclipse IDE - http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Phonegap Plugin (helps quickly package Sencha and Phonegap libraries) - http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap%20Eclipse%20PlugIn%20for%20Android